# Right Aligned labels lists of non-math text

Tags: lists, itemize, labels

I'm trying to produce a labelled list of axioms like so:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[(Reflexivity)] For all $a \in P$ we have that $a \leq a$, 
    \item[(Transitivity)] For all $a,b,c \in P$ s.t. 
                      $a \leq b, b\leq c$ we have that $a\leq c$.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

But this causes the label to run into the left margin of my document.

How would one add a right-aligned label to this list? Perhaps in a similar fashion to a && in an `align` environment?

I'd appreciate any help with this one, thanks.

EDIT - It's been suggested that an item regarding altering left margin spacing would fix this problem. While that is an adequate solution to the problem  of the text running into the margin, I remain interested in a solution to the problem as posed - i.e. a right aligned label.

FURTHER CLARIFICATION - I realise I haven't quite managed to express myself clearly. I would like a bullet pointed list (in itemise, description, whatever) where I have labels (Reflexivity, Transitivity, Anti-Symmetry) to the **right hand side** of the list - that is, right aligned to the right hand margin of the page. I was unable to do this in my MWE so they appear as the bullet pointed list. Would anyone be able to show how to create labels on the RHS:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item For all $a \in P$ we have that $a \leq a$,    (Reflexivity)
    \item For all $a,b,c \in P$ s.t. 
          $a \leq b, b\leq c$ we have that $a\leq c$.   (Transitivity)
%%Here achieved  with spaces
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=22mm}` could help.

Comment: Use `description` instead of `itemize`. Alternatively use `labeling` (needs either a KOMA-Script class or package `scrextend`). Depending on the class, there could be other solutions. So please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Schweinebacke I've updated the question to include the class - article

Comment: Also related: [How to define the indentation for the second line of a multiline item with custom label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204049/how-to-define-the-indentation-for-the-second-line-of-a-multiline-item-with-custo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two variants with a `description` environment, `enumitem` and `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[font = \normalfont, labelsep = 2em]
    \item[{\eqparbox{A}{(Reflexivity)}}] For all $a \in P$ we have that $a \leq a$,
    \item[\eqparbox{A}{(Transitivity)}] For all $a,b,c \in P$ s.t.
                      $a \leq b, b\leq c$ we have that $a\leq c$.
\end{description}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{description}[font = \normalfont, labelsep = 2em]
    \item[{\eqparbox{A}{\hfill(Reflexivity)}}] For all $a \in P$ we have that $a \leq a$,
    \item[\eqparbox{A}{\hfill(Transitivity)}] For all $a,b,c \in P$ s.t.
                      $a \leq b, b\leq c$ we have that $a\leq c$.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update*:

A code for the clarified question, with `listliketab`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listliketab, tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\storestyleof{itemize}
\begin{listliketab}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}LXl@{}}
 \textbullet & For all $a \in P$ we have that $a \leq a$, & (Reflexivity) \\
\textbullet & For all $a,b,c ∈ P$ s.t. \newline
                          $a \leq b, b\leq c$ we have that $a\leq c$. & \makecell[tl]{\\(Transitivity)}
\end{tabularx}
\end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting. This isn't quite what I had in mind, I've clarified further in the OP.

Comment: @BenReynolds: I've added a code which corresponds better to what you're asking.