# How to set leftmargin of description to width of a particular label in enumitem?

Tags: enumitem, description

I'd like to make a timeline with a `description` environment.

If I use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=*,label=0000]
\item[1987]Something really exciting happened in that year, but I’m not sure exactly what.
\item[1990]Bar
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: Missing control sequence inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
\inaccessible 
l.7 \begin{description}[leftmargin=*]
```

It seems that `label=0000` doesn't work for `description` environments?

If I simply put `leftmargin=2.8em` (for this particular case), then I get what I want: the second line of the first item lines up with the first line:

[image: What I'd like to get]

But obviously I'd prefer to achieve this by giving the label to be measured dynamically.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358507/hanging-indent-for-text, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204049/how-to-define-the-indentation-for-the-second-line-of-a-multiline-item-with-custo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelwidth =\widthof{\bfseries9999}, leftmargin = !]
\item[1987]Something really exciting happened in that year, but I’m not sure exactly what.
\item[1990]Bar
\end{description}
\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt, widest = {\bfseries9999}, leftmargin =*, font = \bfseries]
\item[1987]Something really exciting happened in that year, but I’m not sure exactly what.
\item[1990]Bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great; it works and measures the argument as desired. I'd like to understand better what's going on if possible. First, I think it can be simpler: `\begin{description}[noitemsep,labelwidth=widthof{\bfseries9999},leftmargin=!]` seems to work. Secondly, any clue why setting `labelwidth` works but setting `label` gives an error? Is it a bug in `enumitem`?

Comment: Thanks for your remark. You're right: `leftmargin=!` works (and it is indeed simpler). I thought I has  tried it , but it didn't work for some reason. As I tested  several other possibilities, I probably forgot this one. I've  modified the code. For your second question, I don't quite understand what you mean with ‘setting label’, for a description environment?

Comment: Answer accepted,  thanks. I mean, why does setting `label=0000` in the optional parameter to `\begin{description}`, as I did in my question, give an error?

Comment: Probably because there can be no more or less standard pre-defined label for a description environment as there is for enumerate or itemize. I even tried `widest=` (which can be a string), but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `labeling`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{labeling}{9999}
\item[1987]Something really exciting happened in that year, but I’m not sure exactly what.
\item[1990]Bar
\end{labeling}

\end{document}
```

[image: result using scrextend]

If you already use a KOMA-Script class, you can and should omit package `scrextend`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{labeling}{9999}
\item[1987]Something really exciting happened in that year, but I’m not sure exactly what.
\item[1990]Bar
\end{labeling}

\end{document}
```

[image: result using KOMA-Script class]

Comment: Thanks very much for this; this looks like a decent answer, but I'm going to prefer the one that uses `enumitem` which I'm already using (and I'm not using KOMA-Script for this document; maybe II should be!).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder; I've upvoted both answers, as they're both good!