# Align multiple lines of text in itemize

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, description

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and I'm currently trying to create my CV using the software. I'm trying to write down different coding languages that I can use. I'm currently looks like the following but I want where it says data handling (or any of the description) to line up with the start of the description

- **Python**  -    functions, modules, dictionaries, recursion, machine learning, blockchain,                    chatbots, statistics, data visualisation, data handling

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question, but it seems you want to indent the second line on a labelled item list. If so, this was already answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204049/how-to-define-the-indentation-for-the-second-line-of-a-multiline-item-with-custo

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's one way of doing it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\listHeading}[1]{\parbox{1.7cm}{\textbullet\hspace{5pt}\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[\listHeading{Python}] functions, modules, dictionaries, recursion, machine learning, blockchain, chatbots, statistics, data visualisation, data handling
        \item[\listHeading{C++}] functions, modules, dictionaries, recursion, machine learning, blockchain, chatbots, statistics, data visualisation, data handling
        \item[\listHeading{Java}] functions, modules, dictionaries, recursion, machine learning, blockchain, chatbots, statistics, data visualisation, data handling
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If you use a heading longer than python you may need to increase the width of the `\parbox` to more than `1.7cm`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item\textbf{Python }functions, modules, dictionaries, recursion,\\ machine learning, blockchain, chatbots, statistics, data visualisation, data handling
\item \textbf{Python}\qquad  functions, modules, dictionaries, recursion,\\ machine learning, blockchain, chatbots, statistics, data visualisation, data handling
\item \textbf{Python }\hspace{2cm} functions, modules, dictionaries, recursion,\\ machine learning, blockchain, chatbots, statistics, data visualisation, data handling
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```